# Como implementar token para resetar senha?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC que criei sem template (do zero mesmo).
Gostaria de implementar uma função de recuperar senha, mas não sei bem por onde começar.

1. Qual o método usado para gerar um Token seguro que expire em um
   tempo determinado? E qual a melhor forma de gerar um link com
   ele?
2. Preciso armazenar o Token no banco de dados ou ele fica "vivo" na
   memória do servidor pelo tempo determinado?
3. Ao acessar o link com o Token, como fazer a validação do mesmo?

Comment: Não gosto muito da ideia de usar isto mas dê uma olhada: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.generatepasswordresettoken(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Uma resposta no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19036559/221800. Dependendo do que está usando pode ser útil: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28112472/221800 Ou http://stackoverflow.com/a/24211766/221800

Comment: Gostei muito dessa resposta do SO, mas o cara não diz o que é `IdentityManager`. E aí não da pra seguir em frente.

Comment: Eu também não conheço mas sei que ele é importante nessa tecnologia: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx e http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Entendi, mas eu não gostaria de instalar mais um pacote no projeto. Acho que vou usar a opção do seu primeiro comentário mesmo. Muito obrigado. Só não entendi por que você não gosta...

Comment: Então faz na mão, se preocupe com todos os riscos e dificuldades que vários profissionais especialistas no assunto tiveram e levaram meses ou anos para chegar nisso :) O que eu não gosto é o 1o. link só. Eu não sei bem como ele funciona mas me pareceu uma bela gambiarra (ainda que talvez resolva a questão de forma simples). O `IdentityManager` parece ser mais adequado.

Comment: Quer montar um provider novo? qual a necessidade disso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente você vai precisar de uma tabela para armazenar as requisições de alteração de senha, vamos chama-la de password_change_requests e nela será necessário ter as seguintes informações.

Id da tabela (recomendado que será um GUID)

Id do usuário

Tempo para expirar

Após a criação dessa tabela seu processo deverá funcionar da seguinte forma;

1. Na tela de login é recomendado ter um link “Esqueceu a senha?”, onde o usuário será encaminhado para uma página onde irá digitar seu login ou e-mail e terá um botão “Continuar”.
2. Após clicar em “Continuar” o sistema irá salvar o id do usuário na tabela password_change_requests e enviará um e-mail para o usuário passando como parâmetro na url o id da tabela password_change_requests ou seja : http://www.mysite.com/forgotpassword?ID={id da tabela password_change_requests}
3. Ao entrar na página para cadastrar uma nova senha o sistema irá verificar se o id passado por query string existe na tabela password_change_requests e se ele não está com o tempo expirado.
4. Caso esteja tudo em ordem o usuário poderá alterar a sua senha.
5. Após informar a nova senha você deve apagar esse registro evitando assim que seja usado novamente.

Comment: Foi exatamente a alternativa que consegui ver. Eu estava procurando algo diferente, algo nativo da Microsoft, mas acabei implementando de forma semelhante a que você propôs. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela resposta, ela é uma solução para o problema. +1